# How to pass arguments in cron job function

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Im totaly new in wordpress php and cron. So, I have a task. I need to take data from a form and put it into a cron function.

This is me code. I created custom plugin page in wordpress admin panel and try to run this code.
actually the code works if I enter a article id instead of a variable $post_id;

```
function cron_add_one_minute( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['one_minute'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display'  => 'One in minute'
    );
    return $schedules;
};
    if(!empty($_POST) && ($_POST['btnaup']) && !wp_next_scheduled( 'update_post' )) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'one_minute', 'update_post');
    }

    if(isset( $_POST['btnaup'])) {
        $post_id = $_POST['id'];
        $b = $_POST['days'];
    }

add_action( 'update_post', 'update_my_post', 10, 1);

function update_my_post( $post_id ){
        $time = current_time('mysql');
 
        wp_update_post( array (
            'ID'            => $post_id, 
            'post_date'     => $time,
            'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time ),
            'post_modified' => $time,
            'post_modified_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date($time),
        )  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) for `wp_schedule_event`, the fourth parameter, which you are 't currently using, is `$args`

> Array containing arguments to pass to the hook's callback function. Each value in the array is passed to the callback as an individual parameter.
>
> The array keys are ignored.
>
> Default: array()

This means you should be able to use:

```php
if (!empty($_POST) && ($_POST['btnaup']) && !wp_next_scheduled('update_post')) {
    $data = [
        $_POST['id'],
    ];

    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'one_minute', 'update_post', $data);
}
```

Your `update_my_post` function should just work then.

Comment: I am very grateful, it really works, I looked through a bunch of pages on the Internet, but I did not find anything like this before